# Share my account info doesn't appear in Account menu

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

My wife doesn't to share her Whatsapp account information with Facebook. When she  got the Whatsapp notice, she clicked the phone's back button. We tried to follow the [official FAQ](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/general/26000016) or any number of article repeating the same insstruction, but Whatsapp's Account menu doesn't have the new `Share my account info` checkbox shown in the article. Is this because of Whatsapp version? What can I do to stop this sharing?

On my phone I cleared the checkbox and clicked "I agree". I don't see this option in my account menu either...

**Phone:** Samsung Galaxy S3 i9305, Android 4.3, Whatsapp version 2.16.225
**My Phone:** Nokia Lumia 920, Windows Phone 8.1, Whatsapp version 2.16.172

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am having the same problem. I believe I pressed "not now" (back button) instead of agreeing immediately to the terms of service.  According to an 'idigitaltimes' article* from two days ago:

"If you want a little time to think over your decision, you have until September 25 to accept the terms. You can press “Not Now” which essentially means you haven’t agreed to the new terms. As the expiration for the new terms agreement draws near, WhatsApp will remind you again to agree to the terms. You can then choose to leave the green Facebook sharing check marked to share or uncheck it to opt out of sharing."

We want to address this issue right now... But it looks like we will have to wait until Whatsapp 'offers' the new terms of service again.  It's fishy.

*ARTICLE:
http://www.idigitaltimes.com/whatsapp-facebook-opt-out-how-stop-ad-related-data-sharing-between-your-accounts-552594

Comment: I guess we'll have to wait and see - I'll update when something happens.

Comment: Eventually the pop-up came again, and this time she unchecked correctly. I must say this behavior is indeed fishy.